# Manifest button missing in Tortoise HG

Tags: tortoisehg

In one instance of Tortoise HG I have, the Manifest button is nowhere to be found and I cannot find how to get it back.  Any ideas?  Was it removed in this version (2.11) or is it hidden somehow?

[image]

Here is the button mentioned in the accepted answer below:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is in the commit-details widget now. On the left side next to the file filter edit box, there is a icon-button (looks like a document). If you click it, you will get the manifest of the selected version.

Unfortunately it is not so easy to get to the manifest of the working copy, though, because that button doesn't show up in the status widget, which gets automatically selected if you click the working copy in the graph view. However, you can still get it by means of pressing the toolbar button for revision details, which will switch your status widget to commit-details again, but now for the working copy.

[image]

Comment: I much prefer the previous Manifest implementation in that you could choose to just view files that were changed/add/deleted (excluding clean). The new manifest view seems to be the equivalent of the previous manifest view but with "clean" always selected (which I always deselected).

Comment: Just found out that you can simply right-click the manifest and select "List Options" and de-select "clean" from there.  OK, I am back in love. :)